# What does a commutative diagram say about morphism equality?

Tags: category-theory

When we draw a commutative diagram, we commonly conclude that (the composition of) specific morphisms are equal. This is done as follows:

- draw the diagram,
- find two disjoint paths (made of successive morphisms) from one object to another,
- conclude that the composition of morphisms along the first path is equal to the composition of morphisms along the second.

However two paths that share the same origin and end do not necessarily mean that the respective morphisms are equal. This becomes obvious if one considers a monoid (i.e. a category with a single object) that has two distinct morphisms, e.g. the additive group of integers modulo $n$, $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +)$, with morphisms (a) identity and (b) increment by $k \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

This tension becomes a problem in commutative diagrams with three sides:
\begin{align*}
A \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} & B \\
h\searrow & \downarrow{g} \\
& C
\end{align*}
Here we can say that "the diagram commutes, therefore $h = g \circ f$", but the argument from the previous paragraph shows that this result could be misguided.

**Question:** When we have a commutative diagram, how should we interpret the resulting equality of implicated morphisms?

Maybe the answer is that commutative diagrams only allow us to conclude equality *up to isomorphism*? If so, can we deduce any property of this isomorphism?

Related:

- [Symmetric Monoidal Categories and Evil Relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95881/symmetric-monoidal-categories-and-evil-relations?newreg=c8a41b6e08194adfb9f212e8200b5aab)
- [Why doesn't the definition of a category require an explicit notion of morphisms equality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3054271/why-doesnt-the-definition-of-a-category-require-an-explicit-notion-of-morphisms)

Comment: There is equality **if and only if** the diagram is commutative. This is a part of the definition of "commutative diagram". If there is no equality then we state that the diagram is not commutative.

Comment: No in a commutativze diagram the equality is usually really equality, not up to iso.

Comment: "However two paths that share the same origin and end do not necessarily mean that the respective morphisms are equal." That's exactly to point: they don't have to be equal, so requiring them to be equal is a non-trivial constraint---an equation to be solved.
As for "up to iso," that's something that happens in a 2-category, where you have morphisms between morphisms.

Comment: Thanks @BartoszMilewski, you pinpointed my confusion exactly. Also thanks for your amazing book!